# How to read all elements in a list at the same time using if statement?

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

I have a project that goes like this:

```
e_list = [[], [1], [1], [2], [3], [3], [5], [4, 7], [6], [8, 9], [10]]
s_follow_int = [[2, 3], 4, [5, 6], 8, 7, 9, 8, 10, 10, 11]

precedence = e_list[follow_finish_act - 1]
if len(precedence) > 1:
    if precedence in finish_act:
        q_active.append(follow_finish_act)
    else:
        q_active = q_active
else:
    q_active.append(follow_finish_act)
```

The objective is before adding the `follow_finish_act` or follow-up activity of a finish activity, its `precedence` must be checked first. If `all precedence` are in `finish_act`, then `follow_finish_act` can be added to `q_active`. If not, `q_active` remains.

The problem with the code above is if I have:

```
 finish_act = [4]
 follow_finish_act = 8 # from s_follow_int
 precedence of follow_finish_act = [4, 7] # from e_list
```

Since `Activity 7` is still not in `finish_act`, then `follow_finish_act 8` cannot be added to `q_active`. The thing is, with the code above, even if `7` is already in `finish_act` alongside 4, it still won't add 8 to `q_active`. I tried changing it to `if all(precedence) in finish_act`, but it automatically adds 8 even if 7 is still not finished.

Expected output if 7 is not finished:

```
q_active = []
```

If both 4 and 7 are in finish_act, then, the expected output is:

```
q_active = [8]
```

What changes should I make for the `If precedence...` to get what I wanted?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out already! I used all function for solving this problem.

```
check = all(item in finish_act for item in precedence)
    if check is True:
        q_active.append(follow_finish_act)
    else:
        q_active = q_active
```